# install python egg files through build tool

Tags: java, python, maven, maven-3, egg

I am making a project that is primarily in java and meant for java developers but there is a specific library I need to use that uses python.

Assuming the developers have python installed is there a way to automate the installation .egg files in a way that could be run with the same command I use to build the java files (I use maven)

what developer needs to run to setup entire environment:

`mvn clean install`

And this will download the egg files needed and keep them updated.